# Airflow scheduler crash when we Trigger DAG from Airflow web-server

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow scheduler process crashes if we start turning on the DAG and Trigger DAG from Airflow web-server.

**Airflow Version - **v1.10.4**

**Redis server v=5.0.7**

**executor = CeleryExecutor**

```
broker_url = 'redis://:password@redis-host:2287/0'
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host/dbname

result_backend = 'db+postgresql://user:password@host/dbname'
```

**Crashes with Below Error message .**

```
scheduler_job.py:1325} ERROR - Exception when executing execute_helper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1323, in _execute
    self._execute_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1412, in _execute_helper
    self.executor.heartbeat()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 132, in heartbeat
    self.trigger_tasks(open_slots)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 203, in trigger_tasks
    cached_celery_backend = tasks[0].backend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 146, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 1037, in backend
    return self.app.backend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1223, in backend
    return self._get_backend()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 940, in _get_backend
    self.loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 74, in by_url
    return by_name(backend, loader), url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 54, in by_name
    cls = symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 57, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'db
```

Why is the scheduler crashing when DAG is triggered? 
I've tried running `pip install DB` but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do

```
$ airflow initidb
```

before trying to start the `webserver`?
Also, you seem to be using `python 2.7`, are you sure it is compatible with the latest version of `airflow` you are using? 
I was using `python 3.5.2` with latest `airflow` and it did not work for me and thus I had to downgrade my `airflow` version a little.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states. You must not have set up your db properly.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is not compatible with Python version 2.7
Run airflow with python 3.6 and then create db user and grant privileges and then run the command "**airflow initdb**". This will initialize your database in the airflow.